Is there a way to embed Azure AD admin creds to a script to bypass UAC prompt? (PS)
I've created a PowerShell script to clean endpoint devices joined to Entra, but I'm encountering issues with streamlining the UAC credential entry for admin processes like DISM. Running the script as an administrator with the command (Start-Process PowerShell -verb runas -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File','Script.ps1') only leads to a UAC prompt for Entra credentials. This is also the case when using the -verb RunAs parameter. If an Entra admin is logged in on the endpoint device, the UAC prompt only requires a click on "YES," but if a regular user is signed in, it asks for full credentials. I want to know if there's a method to embed the admin credentials within the script to simplify the UAC prompt for the end user to a single click on "YES," instead of entering credentials. Any help is appreciated!

You cannot bypass the UAC prompt entirely, as it is a built-in Windows security feature to prevent unauthorized processes from gaining elevated privileges. You can configure the UAC settings to reduce prompts as per- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disabling-uac-approval-for-specific-programs-in/745a3740-679a-42f9-9c51-59475c9cd2ff
another way is create a scheduled task that runs the script with elevated permissions, bypassing the UAC prompt entirely as mentioned here- https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-programs-elevated-without-getting-the-uac-prompt/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't think you can completely bypass the UAC prompt, as it is a built-in Windows security feature to prevent unauthorized processes from gaining elevated privileges. However, as a workaround you have two options
Option1- Scheduled Task with Highest Privileges
Option2- User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators** and set it to "Elevate without prompting".
You can refer to the links I shared above and create a script that will run elevated tasks
Write-Host "Starting DISM Cleanup..."
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
Write-Host "Cleaning up temporary files..."
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Temp\*" -Recurse -Force
Write-Host "Maintenance completed successfully!"

Store the AD (Entra) Admin creds in Windows Credential Manager
cmdkey /add:AzureAD\AdminUsername /user:AdminUsername /pass:AdminPassword


Schedule a task to run the script with Admin Privileges
$scriptPath = "C:\Scripts\Script.ps1"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "AzureAD\AdminUsername" -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $scriptPath"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Run-AdminScript" -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -Action $action

Since I'm not on AD and don't have entra creds, I'm using local admin to automate the task execution to simplify this, but you can use your entra creds. Replace "AzureAD\AdminUsername" with your actual Azure entra admin details.
Deploy the Script to your VM
az vm run-command invoke \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name arkovm \
  --command-id RunPowerShellScript \
  --scripts "New-Item -Path C:\Scripts -ItemType Directory; Set-Content -Path C:\Scripts\Script.ps1 -Value '<script_content_here>'"


After setting up the task, you can verify its status
az vm run-command invoke \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name arkovm \
  --command-id RunPowerShellScript \
  --scripts "Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName 'Run-AdminScript'"



Thank you, I will try this, and fingers crossed it works!
